# What's the origin of /ʎ/ sound of "gli"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, letters

Most of the current Italian pronunciation is retained from Ecclesiastical Latin, such as *ce/ci, ge/gi, gn*.

There's one sound, *gli*, that I can't find the origin of. Many words containing *gli* that, dating back to Latin, was *le/li* or *lle/lli* (e.g. *illi* → *gli*, *me**li**us* → *me**gli**o*).

This sound is also present in some other Romance languages, like French *ille*, Spanish *ll* and Portuguese *lh*, but not Romanian (no such sound).

I'm guessing this sound was imported from other language families (Germanic / Slavic) some time around the collapse of the (Western) Roman Empire?

Comment: I'm quite sure that French doesn't have the same sound. If you mean, say, the last phoneme in the pronunciation of _paille_, that would be /j/, not /ʎ/.

Comment: @DaG Not exactly. I mean *ill* + vowel (excluding *unstable e*), like *-illé*.

Comment: Like _mouillé_? It's again a /j/ phoneme. If we trust [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais), the phoneme /ʎ/ doesn't occur in French.

Comment: @DaG Then I must have learned something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: In any case, your intuition is interesting, since apparently the outcome of Vulgar Latin “-llj-” (see my answer) has been /ʎ/ (or /ʎʎ/) in Standard Italian, but /j/ both in French and in some varieties of Italian, like the Roman one, where “son” is _fijo_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serianni's *Italiano*, speaking of palatal sounds in Italian and why they are always geminated between vowels (/ʎʎ/, /ɲɲ/ and /ʃʃ/), explains (section I.47):

> Le ragioni della pronuncia intensa di queste consonanti risalgono all'etimo latino. Infatti le tre palatali provengono nella quasi totalità dei casi da una base latina o latino-volgare con consonante intensa: per esempio *figlio* < **fīlljum* (invece del classico *fīlium*), *bagno* < **bănnjum* (invece di *bălneum*), *lascia* < *lāxat* ...

So, apparently there is no influence from other linguistic families, but a direct derivation from different but similar-sounding Latin or Vulgar Latin consonants.